# SQL conditional join with deifferent fields

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

In my query i want to join two tables based on the value of a field (say field1). Depending on the value of the field1 the join would EITHER be:

`field3 = field4  OR field5 = field6`

Something like

```
join on    
  CASE FIELD1    
   When 1 THEN FIELD 2 = FIELD3    
   When 2 THEN FIELD 4 = FIELD5    
  END
```

I am doing something like this at the moment

```
 .... join on  (field1=1 AND field2=field3) OR (field1=2 AND field4=field5)
```

but it takes ages to run the query. The two conditions individually take less than 7 secs each

How can i do this?

Comment: `join on (field1=1 AND field2=field3) OR (field1=2 AND field4=field5)` - this is unconventional syntax. What database are you using? Please provide your actual query.

Comment: `OR` conditions are not easy to optimize and they are usually a symptom of bad design. Can you post the actual tables' structure?

Comment: i am using sql server. The actual query is very large but it's this line that is creating a problem. if i remove the OR part then it runs in under 8 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend against this approach. You are forcing the db to run a query it can't do anything to optimise. Instead look at your tables and see if there isn't something that can be done to split the data so this conditional isn't needed.

Alternatively if you really need to do this then the fastest way to do it is run two queries and `union` the results:

```
select * from table as x where x.field1 = 1 AND x.field2 = x.field3
union [ALL]
select * from table as y where x.field1 = 2 AND y.field4 = y.field5
```

This should be far faster.

Comment: Actually union without ALL. Because you might get the same row twice in case the condition fits both cases.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan it's unlikely `field1` is going to be both 1 and 2 at the same time :)

Comment: @vlad but in case you have (field1 = 1 and 2=2) or (field2 = 2 and 3=3) the UNION ALL will produce one more result then UNION.

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan that's not the condition the OP has: it's `(field1=1 and 2=2) or (field1=2 and 3=3)`. @MichaelAllen has a typo is his response, but OP is clear: the 'case' statement is only for `field1`. In this case, `UNION ALL` should be faster since it avoids the sort.

Comment: yeah that was psuedo-sql with no real checks to see if it works. Should work in theory, may need some modification, typos probably exist

Answer (score 1):

It takes ages because the or will not let you use indexes. The simplest solution what I can think of, is to make 2 selects and union them.

```
select ...
from ...
join ...
   on  (field1=1 AND field2=field3)
union
select ...
from ...
join ...
   on  (field1=2 AND field4=field5)
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Altough it makes the query verbose (as the query iteself withouth he union is large) but it does work and returns result in about 15 secs...

Comment: As someone suggested also .. put union all and it will be faster .. I was not paying attention at that moment.

Comment: @user1108205, there is nothing wrong with verbosity in a sql query, the most efficient querirs are often more verbose. Efficiency is critical in database querying, so the techniques that produce it are far better than short, elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "or" in a join condition is that it impedes the use of indices and tends to encourage nested loop joins.  I would recommend doing the join twice:

```
from A left outer join
     B b1
     on a.field2 = b2.field3 left outer join
     B b2
     on a.field4 = b2.field5
```

The left outer joins make sure you keep all rows.  You can do additional logic in the SELECT or WHERE clauses to get the full logic you want.

Comment: I tried your solution but futher down in the query a field from the table B is used in a join as well. That field should come from the same alias that matched the condition... i used coalesce but no luck in performance.

Comment: The `coalesce()` also impedes optimization.  You should ask another question, with more detail on what you are doing, including the database engine and more specifics about the overall query.

Answer (score 0):

> "it takes ages to run the query. The two conditions individually take
>   less than 7 secs each"

When you run the individual queries the database can figure out a clear-cut execution path.  But they will be *different* execution paths for each condition.    When you attempt to combine the two conditions the database has no easy to reconcile them, so it does something slow - probably a full table scan.

How you solve this depends on your flavour of RDBMS and a whole host of other factors.   I will let other people give you sonme guesses about how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_parent
WHERE pid = 
CASE 
WHEN pid =1
THEN (
SELECT id
FROM data_parent, test
WHERE data_parent.pid = test.id
)
```

data_parent and test are two tables

data_parent has column pid and test has an column rpid as foreign key.

This works and gives me the output.